# Auto escape html tags while creating pdf from html using xhtml2pdf

Tags: python, flask, xhtml2pdf

I have successfully converted a html page to pdf. Thanks for this cool module. 
But now problem is....I have a Download link for the generated file in the same html page, 
which too gets printed... :D

`<nav><a href='/static/pdf/xyz.pdf'>Download</a><nav>`

Is there a way to escape the anchor tag or anything that can be done to ignore certain html elements.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Solution...A CSS trick solved it.. :D

```
<style>
    @media print {
        nav { display: none;}
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the quotes aren't closed in your example. I bet if you close them, it will resolve the issue.

```
<a href='/static/pdf/xyz.pdf'>Download</a>
```

Comment: Opps, my mistake while posting. Its not the quotes issue.

Comment: Using media print opetion in css solved the problem. I have edited the post with solution. Cheers !!!

Comment: @user1051068 If you put your solution in an answer instead of editing into the question, then you can "accept" your own answer so that it shows up in the appropriate place and your question is flagged as having an accepted answer, so is no longer considered "open" and still awaiting answers.